# Calculating a new accumulative column in a data frame based on existing columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset that i want to use to evaluate my forecast.
The dataset looks like this:

```
tibble(article=rep(21,5), estimated_sales=rep(50, 5), week=c(38,39,40,41,42), stock=c(500, 400, 375, 400, 350), purchase=c(0,0,0,50,0))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  article estimated_sales  week stock purchase
    <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1      21              50    38   500        0
2      21              50    39   400        0
3      21              50    40   375        0
4      21              50    41   400       50
5      21              50    42   350        0
```

Finally, I would like to have a data set with a new variable `real_sales` calculated as follows (e.g. for week 40):
375 (stock for week 40) - 400 (stock for week 41) + 50 (purchase in week 41) = 25, which is then the observation for the `real_sales` variable for week 40.

A desired outcome dataset would look like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Article estimated_sales  week stock purchase rea_sales
    <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1      21              50    38   500        0       100
2      21              50    39   400        0        25
3      21              50    40   375        0        25
4      21              50    41   400       50       100
5      21              50    42   300        0        NA
```

Comment: The last value of `stock` is 350 in your input whereas 300 in your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `lead` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(real_sales = stock - lead(stock) + lead(purchase))

#  article estimated_sales  week stock purchase real_sales
#    <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#1      21              50    38   500        0        100
#2      21              50    39   400        0         25
#3      21              50    40   375        0         25
#4      21              50    41   400       50         50
#5      21              50    42   350        0         NA
```

and `shift` in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, real_sales := stock - shift(stock, type = 'lead') + 
                          shift(purchase, type = 'lead')]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` for this

```
df$real_sales <- with(df, stock - c(stock[-1], NA) +
                  c(purchase[-1], NA))
df$real_sales
#[1] 100  25  25  50  NA
```